# C: How to call functions from dll API?

Tags: c, api, dll, build

I am trying to write a program that uses a C API. This API just provides a `api.h` header file, a `.dll` and a `.lib`.
It is using `__stdcall` exports.

I tried including the `api.h` and adding the `.lib` and `.dll` file, but I still have the following error to the libraries path, but I still have the following error:

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project TestLibsp ****

**** Internal Builder is used for build               ****
gcc -LC:\Users\nbarraille\workspace\TestLibsp\lib -oTestLibsp.exe src\main.o
src\main.o: In function `main':
C:\Users\nbarraille\workspace\TestLibsp\Debug/../src/main.c:83: undefined reference to `sp_session_create@8'
C:\Users\nbarraille\workspace\TestLibsp\Debug/../src/main.c:86: undefined reference to `sp_error_message@4'
C:\Users\nbarraille\workspace\TestLibsp\Debug/../src/main.c:92: undefined reference to `sp_session_login@12'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Build error occurred, build is stopped
Time consumed: 721  ms
```

Here is my .c file:

```
#include "api.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    sp_session *sp;
    sp_error err;
    sp_session_config spconfig;

    /* Create session */
    sp_error err = sp_session_create(&spconfig, &sp);
}
```

And here is the definition of the function I am trying to call in the `api.h`

```
#ifndef SP_LIBEXPORT
#ifdef _WIN32
#define SP_LIBEXPORT(x) x __stdcall
#else
#define SP_LIBEXPORT(x) x
#endif
#endif

SP_LIBEXPORT(sp_error) sp_session_create(const sp_session_config *config, sp_session **sess);
```

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to link against the library with `gcc -l<libname> -L<libpath>`. I guess you are using eclipse, so you can easily add the lib in Project -> Properties -> C/C++Build -> Settings -> GCC C++ Linker -> Library

Comment: My `.dll` and `.lib` files are in a `lib` folder in my project directory. Right now, I'm already adding this `lib` directory to the libpath in the MinGW C Linker. When I add the `.dll` and `.lib` one by one (-l), I have the following error: `c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lC:\Users\nbarraille\workspace\TestLibsp\lib\libspotify.dll`, even if the files are at the specified location.

Comment: It's `-llibspotify` or even `-lspotify` without any file extension and/or path. The path is set via `-L` as you are already doing. The extension is looked up automatically. Edit: Backslashes probably are a bad idea too, use forward slashes instead.